# Ubuntu Mate 20.04 very (<<5kbps) slow wired ethernet on Dell Optiplex desktop computer

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, mate

Extremely slow (<5kbps) wired ethernet with Ubuntu 20.04.  None of the similar answers apply.  New to me, off-lease Dell optiplex.  Bog stock.  32GB main memory.  500GB Crucial SSD. Computer is connected to a Hughsnet satellite modem.  I'm currently booted on 19.04 live thumbdrive because I can't access the net with the installed 20.04 version.

`sudo lshw -c network`  shows

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 00
   serial: d8:9e:f3:0a:de:f5
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.1.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:124 memory:ef000000-ef01ffff
```

Any more troubleshooting or fixes would be much appreciated.

I've been working on this for 2 days and am at my wit's end.

Does anyone know if the network problems have been fixed in 21.04?  I want to stay with LTS releases but I'll upgrade if that can get my network back.

I should add that I have purchased and returned 3 different PCIe combo wifi/bluetooth cards recommended for Linux.  None of them worked with this version.  Also tried a USB WiFi dongle that worked before and it too fails to connect with 20.04.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *hirsute* hippo [21.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.04 is 22 April 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539) when your *hirsute* question will be on-topic here.